# (Interface)object конвертировать в аналогичный struct

Tags: c#, интерфейс, преобразование-типов

У меня есть структура

```
struct Component
{
    string Name;
    double Fraction;
    ...
}
```

И есть внешняя библиотека (от Aspen HYSYS), в которой есть интерфейс Component (без I в начале, но это интерфейс), и его объекты тоже имеют Name, а Fraction можно получить по этому объекту из другого места.
Можно ли сделать static implicit operator, который бы преобразовывал библиотечный Component в мою структуру?

Comment: Может, проще унаследоваться от этого интерфейса?

Comment: Можно использовать библиотеку Automapper чтобы замаппить объект по свойствам.

Comment: Можно создать конструктор в вашей структуре/классе, который будет принимать внешний интерфейс и копировать все нужные свойства.

Comment: Унаследоваться будет сложновато, это скорее всего с циклическими зависимостями только. Использовать Automapper наверное все-таки нерационально, оперируем все-таки с простенькой структурой. Попробую тогда сделать partial struct, и дописать там конструктор.